# Why can't Jenkins copy these files?

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins. I am trying to get it to build a project and then copy the artifacts to a particular location. I believe I have the permissions setup correctly, but I get "permission denied" errors when that build step is run.

The code is written in Clojure. Jenkins correctly pulls the code from Github. Then Jenkins runs "lein uberjar". The files are successfully created.

I have an "Execute shell" as a build step in Jenkins. The shell command is:

```
cp /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/api/workspace/target/*.jar  /home/jenkins/api
```

If I ssh to the server, and sudo to root, and then su to "jenkins", I can run the above command and it works perfectly. However, when Jenkins does this, the output contains:

```
+ cp /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/api/workspace/target/instaphoto-0.1-standalone.jar /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/api/workspace/target/instaphoto-0.1.jar /home/jenkins/api
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/home/jenkins/api/instaphoto-0.1-standalone.jar’: Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/home/jenkins/api/instaphoto-0.1.jar’: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Sending e-mails to: developer@sunflowerforce.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

If I do this:

```
groups jenkins
```

I see:

```
jenkins : jenkins root run-server-software
```

and if I do this:

```
cd /home/jenkins
ls -al 

drwxrwx---  4 jenkins run-server-software 4096 Jul 30 20:21 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 root    root                4096 Jul 30 18:59 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 sunflower  run-server-software 4096 Jul 31 01:06 api
drwxrwxr-x 10 sunflower  run-server-software 4096 Jul 30 19:59 nlp
```

So jenkins belongs to group run-server-software  and group run-server-software    should have permission to do whatever it wants in folders such as api. So why do I get "permission denied"?

Comment: Can you try ```cp -f /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/api/workspace/target/instaphoto-0.1-standalone.jar /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/api/workspace/target/instaphoto-0.1.jar /home/jenkins/api```?

Comment: If you added `jenkins` to that group recently, you may have to restart Jenkins (or the server).

Comment: I would be amazed if I had to restart the server. I will lose respect for Linux if that is true. But I will try it.

Comment: Just to assure: Jenkins' process runs under the user `jenkins?` A `whoami` prior to the `cp ...` in _Execute shell_ prints `jenkins?`

Comment: That would be incredible if jenkins did not run as the user jenkins, but I checked with "ps aux" and, for sure, jenkins does run as the user jenkins: 

jenkins  31658  0.0  8.2 8549000 1268244 ?     Sl   Jul31   4:19 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/jenkins/api//salesslick-0.1-standalone.jar